# Merge array into column row by row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do this without code.

I have an array of 4 columns with an undefined amount of rows, and I want to merge them into 1 column, but **not** by appending columns (so I can't use `{A1:A;B1:C1;C;..}`), but rather by appending cell, line by line.

Example:

**Input**:

```
Val1a Val1b Val1c Val1d
Val2a Val2b Val2c Val2d
Val3a Val3b Val3c Val3d
Val4a Val4b Val4c Val4d
Val5a Val5b Val5c Val5d
...
```

**Output**:

```
Val1a
Val1b
Val1c
Val1d
Val2a
Val2b
Val2c
Val2d
Val3a
...
```

Comment: In the case the code will be your only option: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386840/print-each-field-of-csv-on-newline-without-knowing-number-of-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julien, let's say your sample data above were in the range A1:D5. Use this:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,A1:D5),"/"))`

This assumes that your data itself does not contain a forward slash, which in the formula, is being used as a temporary delimiter. If, for some reason, your data *does* contain a slash (e.g., URLs, etc.), just replace the two instances of the forward slash in the formula with any symbol or combination of symbols that your data *does not* include.

How it works:

1. TEXTJOIN will string together the whole range into one long text string, running left to right per row, separating everything by a delimiter of choice.
2. SPLIT will then split that text string again at those delimiters, which will make a long horizontal array of everything in the original range.
3. TRANSPOSE will take that long horizontal array and change it to a vertical array.

If you then want to keep the *hard data* created by the formula:

1. Select the results range.
2. Hit Ctrl-C to copy it to clipboard.
3. With the range still selected, hit Ctrl-Alt-V to Paste Special.
4. A small clipboard icon will appear at the lower right corner of the range. Click it and choose "Paste values only."